# Odoo10 - Missing CSS and JS files after using reverse proxy Error 111 connection refused

Tags: nginx, odoo, reverse-proxy

We're migrating from old server to a new one, so I've installed Odoo V10.0 on Ubuntu 16.04LTS hosted on Digitalocean.
Everything works just fine, but when I used reverse proxy to access Odoo from port 80 instead of the default 8069 according to [this book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/odoo-10-development/9781785884887/) and upload the old db, all the JS and CSS/LESS files give 404 not found on the website and I get Error 111 connection refused when the server tries to redirect to the online payment gateway.

Here's a screenshot of the error I receive in console
 [image: screenshot]

Here's my Nginx configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-available/odoo:

```
upstream backend-odoo {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream backend-odoo-im { 
    server 127.0.0.1:8072; 
}
server {
    listen 80;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
    listen 443 default;
    # ssl settings
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate
    /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;
    keepalive_timeout 60;

    #increase the upload file size limit
    client_max_body_size 30M;

    # proxy header and settings
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # odoo log files
    access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo-error.log;
    # increase proxy buffer size
    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    # force timeouts if the backend dies
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500
    http_502 http_503;
    # enable data compression
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 4 32k;
    gzip_types text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css;
    gzip_vary on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend-odoo;
    }
    location ~* /web/static/ {
    # cache static data
    proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
    proxy_buffering on;
    expires 864000;
    proxy_pass http://backend-odoo;
    }
    location /longpolling { 
        proxy_pass http://backend-odoo-im;
    }
}
```

Here's Odoo conf file:

```
[options]
addons_path = /odoo/enterprise/addons,/odoo/odoo-server/addons,/odoo/custom/addons,/odoo/server-tools
admin_passwd = xxxxxxxxxxx
csv_internal_sep = ,
data_dir = /odoo/.local/share/Odoo
db_host = False
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = False
db_port = False
db_template = template1
db_user = xxxx
dbfilter = .*
demo = {}
email_from = False
geoip_database = /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat
import_partial = 
limit_memory_hard = 2684354560
limit_memory_soft = 2147483648
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 60
limit_time_real = 120
limit_time_real_cron = -1
list_db = True
log_db = False
log_db_level = warning
log_handler = :INFO
log_level = info
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
logrotate = False
longpolling_port = 8072
max_cron_threads = 2
osv_memory_age_limit = 1.0
osv_memory_count_limit = False
pg_path = None
pidfile = None
proxy_mode = True
reportgz = False
server_wide_modules = web,web_kanban
smtp_password = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = False
syslog = False
test_commit = False
test_enable = False
test_file = False
test_report_directory = False
translate_modules = ['all']
unaccent = False
without_demo = False
workers = 0
xmlrpc = True
netrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
xmlrpc_port = 8069
```

Here's the output of log file in /var/log/nginx/odoo-error.log

```
2017/04/01 06:55:24 [error] 24333#24333: *3196 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "GET /web_planner/static/src/img/odoo_logo.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8069/web_planner/static/src/img/odoo_logo.png", host: "yyy.yy.yyy.yy", referrer: "https://yyy.yy.yyy.yy/?debug=1"
2017/04/01 06:55:25 [error] 24333#24333: *3495 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8069/longpolling/poll", host: "yyy.yy.yyy.yy", referrer: "https://yyy.yy.yyy.yy/web?debug="
2017/04/01 07:01:29 [error] 24333#24333: *4263 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8069/longpolling/poll", host: "yyy.yy.yyy.yy", referrer: "https://yyy.yy.yyy.yy/web?"
2017/04/01 08:03:12 [error] 30741#30741: *5413 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8069/longpolling/poll", host: "yyy.yy.yyy.yy", referrer: "https://yyy.yy.yyy.yy/web?debug=1"
2017/04/01 08:17:38 [error] 30741#30741: *5491 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8069/longpolling/poll", host: "yyy.yy.yyy.yy", referrer: "https://yyy.yy.yyy.yy/web?debug=1"
2017/04/01 08:35:15 [error] 30741#30741: *6308 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8069/longpolling/poll", host: "yyy.yy.yyy.yy", referrer: "https://yyy.yy.yyy.yy/web?debug="
2017/04/01 08:46:38 [error] 30741#30741: *6897 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8069/longpolling/poll", host: "yyy.yy.yyy.yy", referrer: "https://yyy.yy.yyy.yy/web?debug="
```

the output of $`netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8069          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Lastly the output of $`telnet 127.0.0.1 8069`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

the output of $`telnet 127.0.0.1 8072`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

the output of $`telnet 127.0.0.1`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

PS. I didn't apply the SSL certificate yet or the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Comment below lines and try like that.

```
netrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
```